# CakePHP Ajax form - cloning form fields

Tags: cakephp

Using cake 2.2. I currently have a form (built using the form helper) that allows users to add expense claims. Each claim consists of many expenses. So the form contains a row for each expense along with a button that uses jQuery to clone the first row of fields and insert them (with incremented ids/names). The problem is when the form is submitted and there is an error, the cloned fields disappears as the page refreshes (I guess because their not in the dom any more).

The values are still in $this->data so I guess I could manually rebuild them but if I made the form submit by ajax would it solve the problem? IE on error the cloned fields would still remain?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that are built from Javascript will not retain from one page-load to the next.

Either use Ajax (probably ideal), or build out the fields with PHP based on the supplied data.

Either way is fairly "normal" way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks Dave, just wanted confirmation I'm not missing an easier option. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem - glad to help.

Comment: @Dave can you elaborate on each method a bit? What would "use ajax" mean exactly? Does `supplied data` mean non-ajax `$this->request->data`?